# displaying username beside users message in node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So i have a chatroom i built in node.js and socket.io [here](http://billischill.ddns.net:3000) i am able to see the users name beside there join messages and leave messages but not beside messages they send themselves here is my server code

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('adduser', function(username){
socket.username = username;
socket.room = 'General-Chat';
usernames[username] = username;
socket.join('General-Chat');
socket.broadcast.to('General-Chat').emit('updatechat', '<b   class="servertxt">SERVER: </b>', socket.username + ' has connected to this room' + '<hr>');
 socket.emit('welcomeuser', '<b class="servertxt">SERVER:</b> Welcome ',     socket.username + '<hr>');
 socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');
 });
 socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
  // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
  io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
 });
 socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
 socket.leave(socket.room);
 socket.join(newroom);
 socket.emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt"> SERVER </b>', 'you have      connected to '+ newroom + '<hr>');
 // sent message to OLD room
 socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt">    SERVER </b>', socket.username+' has left this room <hr>');
 // update socket session room title
 socket.room = newroom;
 socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt"> SERVER </b>', socket.username+' has joined this room <hr>');
 socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
 });
 console.log('a user connected');
 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
 console.log('user disconected');
 });
 socket.on('chat-message', function (message) {
 console.log('message:', socket.username+': ' + message.text);
 //excludes "socket" from getting the emit
 socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit("chat-message",message);
 });
 });
```

and here is my index.html script

```
    <script>
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function(){
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#chatlog-display-div').append(username + data);
    });
    socket.on('welcomeuser', function(data, username){
        jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append(data + username);
    });
    socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
        $('#rooms').empty();
        $.each(rooms, function(key, value) {
            if(value == current_room){
                $('#rooms').append('<div id="chatroom-box"><center>' + value + '<center></div><hr>');
            }
            else {
                $('#rooms').append('<div id="chatroom-box"><center><a id="chatroom-box-link" href="#" onclick="switchRoom(\''+value+'\')">' + value + '</a></center></div><hr>');
            }
        });
    });
    function switchRoom(room){
        socket.emit('switchRoom', room);
    }

     $('form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

           //gets the value from the message text feild and sets it as the    message var
     var message = {
            text : $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').val()
            }
        if (message.text.trim().length !== 0) {
                        socket.emit('chat-message',message);
                //append the message to the chatlog-display-div
                $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').focus().val('');
                jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append('<div>'+message.text+'</div><hr>');
            }
                        });
           socket.on('chat-message', function (message) {
           jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append('<div>'+message.text+'</div><hr>');
           });

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you having trouble seeing the chat message at the person that tried to send it? i'm having difficulty understanding your question

Comment: i'm sorry about that. but no there messages show up i just cant get it to where it will display there name beside it i have tried putting `socket.username` right beside the part where it appends the message to the div but it makes the whole messages say undefinded

Comment: can someone please help me

Comment: Try to add the username to the message array, it might be not the best way. But it might work :-)